# Making page tab searchable?

Tags: facebook, search, tabs

I have a client that wants their tab application to be searchable in Facebook. You can search for the application itself just fine, but the result comes up separate from the page (with no way of leading back to the page itself).

Is it possible to make a page tab searchable? If not, is there a way of detecting whether or not an application is within a tab (so we could display a custom link back to the page)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It´s not possible to make a page tab searchable at this moment. Apps are searchable, so the solution should be use a specific app. With that app, you can render content in your tab. But when users search, they will land in your app canvas (not in the tab) but you can redirect back to you tab url with javascript. Place this code in your canvas app view:

```
window.location = "your_tab_url"
```